# How can i check if the Gate::before method was used ?

Tags: php, laravel

I used laravel's authorization in my code and defined the before method in my service provider as shown in the documentation:

```
public function before($user, $ability)
{
    if ($user->email == 'super@mail.com') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Sometimes I need to know if the checks were intercepted. So, instead of checking the mail (or any other condition for superuser) in different places, I want to check if this intercepting method is used. I mean instead of using this (if email is equal...) condition in different places again and again. I want to set this super admin condition only once (in the service provider) and then check it when needed. Something like:

```
\Gate::isIntercepted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simply returning `true`, you can return an authorization response:

```php
public function before($user, $ability)
{
    if ($user->email == 'super@mail.com') {
        return $this->allow('superadmin');
    }
}
```

You'll get the response later on if you use `authorize`:

```php
public function update(Post $post)
{
    $response = $this->authorize($post);

    if ($reponse->message() == 'superadmin') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all great thanks. I am new to laravel. Can you please explain it a little bit more in detail?

Comment: when i use "return $this->allow('superadmin')" i got an error. Call to undefined method [allow].

Comment: @Skeletor - you have to `use` the [`HandlesAuthorization`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/HandlesAuthorization.php) trait.

Comment: yes after some struggle i found out that i had to use the trait. thx again @JosephSilber.